# How to print x axis tick marks in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution

Of a part of a mini project where I need to build visualizations depicting relations between various probability distributions, I wanted to use ggplot function wrapped inside manipulate, such that user changes the distribution parameters and see 1 one distribution converging to another. But for the code below, I am not able to show x axis labels at all (e.g: 1,2,3,4 and so on). I tried using labels, breaks and some more options but still have not found a solution. Kindly requesting to help please. Thank you.

```
#poisson distribution
manipulate(
{
data<-data.frame(x=rpois(1000,lamba))
ggplot(data,aes(x=x),bins = 100)+geom_bar()+scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1,20,1))
}
,lamba=slider(0.01,10)
)
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add the pertaining `label` parameter in  `scale_x_discrete()`.
For example here, it can be the same as for `breaks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `scale_x_continuous` and also change the `breaks` to `seq(0,20,1)` to get the ticks for all the bars on the graph; if you want to get the `labels` from `1` instead of `0` then you need to define it inside the `scale_x_continuous` like this: `labels = seq(1,21,1)`.

```
library(manipulate)
library(ggplot2)
manipulate(
  {
    data<-data.frame(x=rpois(1000,lamba))
    ggplot(data,aes(x=x),bins = 100)+geom_bar()+scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20,1))
  }
  ,lamba=slider(0.01,10)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. So basically your idea is to treat the discrete random variable as some continuous just for some coding and printing purpose. I will absorb that :)

Comment: Not quite like that, what you have in mind differs from what you feed into the code. And R cannot read behind the lines, it gets what actually is there.